# How to make grid scrollable on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to make my grid scrollable. I have a grid control that will eventually hold 30-40 rows of data. I populate/create these rows dynamically with code. Every time these rows render on the screen, they try to fit in the height I have set for the grid.  I tried wrapping my grid in scrollviewer but that didn't work. I want to stay away from the listbox because text will get misaligned.  Here is my XAML code for constructing the Grid:

```
            <ScrollViewer Canvas.Left="56" Canvas.Top="354">
        <Grid x:Name="grdWeather"  Canvas.Left="56" Canvas.Top="354" Width="371" ShowGridLines="True" Background="#FFDCB3B3" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MaxHeight="196">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

And here is my code for creating the rows:

```
                for (int t = 0; t <= 30; t++) 
            {
                RowDefinition row1 = new RowDefinition();
                grdWeather.RowDefinitions.Add(row1);

                TextBlock txtTime = new TextBlock();
                txtTime.Text = time;
                txtTime.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, t);
                txtTime.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
                txtTime.Width = 100;
                grdWeather.Children.Add(txtTime);

                TextBlock txtTemp = new TextBlock();
                txtTemp.Text = time;
                txtTemp.Width = 100;
                txtTemp.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, t);
                txtTemp.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
                grdWeather.Children.Add(txtTemp);
            }
```

Any suggestions/feedback are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using a ListBox is definitely a better idea. The problem with your code is the MaxHeight=196 on your Grid. Delete it on it will work